# How can I get multiple answers from a HTML form checkbox response into my google sheet using AppScript separated by commas?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using [this github code](https://github.com/jamiewilson/form-to-google-sheets) to pull responses from my HTML form into a google sheet but I am having an issue where all my data is pulling through fine except for any that is from a checkbox that has multiple-choices available.

Eg:

X OPTION 1
X OPTION 2
X OPTION 3

I have 2 fields like this one is coming through as a blank box on google sheets and the other is only showing the first response (OPTION 1)

I'd like the data to display like OPTION 1, OPTION 2, OPTION 3 on the google sheet, is there a way to do this?

AppScript:

```
var sheetName = 'Sheet1'
var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function intialSetup () {
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
}

function doPost (e) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
      <label>Which of our games are you interested in?</label> <br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Which of our games are you interested in?" value="PHAGEBORN - PC">
      <label for="PHAGEBORN - PC">PHAGEBORN - PC</label><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Which of our games are you interested in?" value="Goblin Gladiators - PC">
      <label for="Goblin Gladiators - PC">Goblin Gladiators - PC</label><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Which of our games are you interested in?"value="Rare Pets - Mobile">
      <label for="Rare Pets - Mobile">Rare Pets - Mobile</label>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div>
      <label>What kind of creator are you?</label><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="What kind of creator are you?" value="TikTok">
      <label for="TikTok">TikTok</label><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="What kind of creator are you?" value="Twitch">
      <label for="Twitch">Twitch</label><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="What kind of creator are you?" value="YouTube">
      <label for="YouTube">YouTube</label><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="What kind of creator are you?" value="Other">
      <label for="Other">Other</label><br>
    </div>
```

Also I tried to input the form from another email address and I need to request access even though I had set the permissions on my AppScript as "anyone" when I deployed as Web app, have I missed a step?

This is my first time using AppScript so am probably missing something very obvious!

Thank you so much!

Comment: Use a form element

Comment: Can you provide your whole script? And, what values are put into the header row of your current Spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I worked it out kind of.

I couldn't get the values to display in the same field in sheets but I amended my HTML so each option had its own unique name value and added a corresponding column on the sheet.

```
<div>
      <label>What kind of creator are you?</label><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="TikTok" value="TikTok">
      <label for="TikTok">TikTok</label><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Twitch" value="Twitch">
      <label for="Twitch">Twitch</label><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="YouTube" value="YouTube">
      <label for="YouTube">YouTube</label><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Other" value="Other">
      <label for="Other">Other</label><br>
    </div>
```

This means I can see each option when they have been chosen, just make sure you have made matching columns in your googlesheet!